# perl regular expression to substitute content of a xml tag content

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing

The following tags are in the same format in the file and not well formed
I want to replace the tags inside user tag with name test with my custom text.
xml parser in perl cant be used as it is not pure xml.

```
   <user name="test">
       <option name="test2">dev</option>
       <option name="test3">csm></option>
    </user> 
    <user name="test12">
       <option name="test21">dev1</option>
       <option name="test31">csm1></option>
    </user>
```

Comment: Using regexes to parse XML is not a great idea. Have you considered using an XML parser instead?

Comment: "and not well formed"? XML is exactly the opposite of that.

Comment: yes its not well formed..I mean there are multiple roots no single root is present.I had to use regular expression to parse it.Its not pure XML.

Comment: @fenway its not pure xml.I have a file in which the configuration is written in such format.

Comment: please dont mark it as negative.Its a valid question

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: @tonystark, add proxy root tag to outer of <user> elements then try perl-xml parser!

Comment: @codeninja I have tried it but of less use.I need to replace the content and again write it to the same file.

Comment: @tonystark, provide your expected output so that we can help you in right direction. in between follow this steps 1. add <proxy> tag to outer of <user> elements 2. do your modifications using xml parser 3. save the results into your file 4. replace the <proxy> tag to empty string

Comment: @codeninja I have a string which is like <option name="test4">dev4</option> , I need to replace the content in user name= "test" tag, with the string using perl file handling and regular expression.I hope I m clear

Comment: Hi all, I m finally done with the requirement.This is how i achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i managed to do it.

```
 open(FILE,"<","menu1.xml");
     open(OUT,">","menu12.xml");
             my @values = split('\n', $data);
    my $ind = 0;

    my $arraysize = @values;

     while (($input = <FILE>)) 
        {
          print OUT $input;
            if($input =~ m/<menu name="">/)
            {
            while (defined($input = <FILE>) && ($input !~ m/<\/menu>/))
            {
            print OUT $input;
            if ($input =~ m/.+user name="(.*)">/ && $1 eq $access_type)
             {
                while (defined($input = <FILE>) && ($input !~ m/<\/user>/))
                 {

                        if($ind < $arraysize)
                        {
                        $input =~ s/<(.*) name="(.*)">(.*)<\/(.*)>/$values[$ind]/;
                        print OUT $input;   
                        $ind = $ind+1;
                        }


                 }
                if($input =~ m/<\/user>/)   
                    {
                     print OUT $input;
                    }           
             }  
            }
              if($input =~ m/<\/menu>/)  
              {
                print OUT $input;
              }       
           }
      }
```